# Is it possible to timestamp a cell when in its adjacent cell, a comment is added or a new reply is added to the comment?

Tags: google-apps-script

I know its very much possible to timestamp a cell when other cells are edited/changed/equals to a specific value.

So I kinda need to know is it feasible to timestamp when comments are added/edited/replied in its adjacent cell.

Any help or support links would be helpful.

Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get Comments via apps script.  You can get Notes with apps script.  Editing a Note or a Comment does not trigger an onEdit event so it would be hard to timestamp it.